# New Arrays and Pointers

Tags: c

I am having a bit of trouble because I am new to C and am not even sure if what I want to do is possible.

I am passing an array called **args** into a function.  Within the function I am also creating a 2D array called **arrayOfArgs**.  What I want to do is to put certain values from args into specific locations in the 2D array called arrayOfArgs.

This is my code so far:

```
int do_command(char **args){
        //this is usually a changing variable depending on the situation, but I've hard coded it to make sense
        int commands = 3;
        char **arrayOfArgs[commands][10];
        //counts which column in arrayOfArgs we are on
        int commandNum = 0;

//Counts which part of a command we are on
        int count = 0;

    //Array Counters
    int i = 0;
    int j;

    //Go through args until we reach the end
    while (args[i] != NULL){
        if(!strcmp(args[i], "|")){
            arrayOfArgs[commandNum][count] = args[i];
            count++;
        }
        else if (strcmp(args[i], "|")) {
            count = 0;
            commandNum++;
        }
        //Looking at the next value in args
        i++;
    }
```

I'm running into problems because the only thing being put into arrayOfArgs is gibberish.  I'm sure I've done something wrong with either the way the arrays are pointing, the way arrayOfArgs was created, or both.

OR is it even possible to go from a 1D to a 2D array like I'm trying?

I'm pretty sure there is a NULL there because earlier I call this loop and it works:

```
for(i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++) {
    printf("Argument %d: %s\n", i, args[i]);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm writing a C Shell, by this way, and I'm writing the part with piping right now.  I'd like to separate commands (separated by the | symbol) into the 2D array.

Comment: Are you explicitly adding a final `NULL` element to `args`?  If you're not, then your loop condition is wrong and will not terminate correctly:  `args[i] != NULL`

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a NULL there because earlier I call a function (Now added to the main question) that goes until NULL and works just fine.

Comment: 1) You could avoid the two dimensional array by just remembering the index of the command, and the number of arguments per command. 2) also: if you don't keep the number of arguments per command, you should add a NULL `arrayOfArgs[commandNum][count++] = NULL;` in the "else if" part (which is just a plain else); just before you reset count to zero. (this is equivalent o replacing the "|" by a NULL pointer) 3) also you could use a for loop instead of a while + spurious increment.

Comment: @Rick_Sch: "Pretty sure"?  I would hope you are absolutely sure as it is required for your program to work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I decided to go a 1D array route rather than a 2D way.  The code now takes args, which were split before as "ls" "-l" "|" "wc" and separates them based on if there is a pipe into a new array called "arrayOfCommands".  The contents of arrayOfCommands are then, once this is through, "ls -l" and "wc".  Here's the code:

```
int do_command(char **args,) {
    const int commands = 2;
    int i = 0;

    int commandNum = 0;
    int firstCommand = 1;

    char *arrayOfCommands[commands];

    //Go through args until we reach the end
    while (args[i] != NULL){
        //First case            
        if(firstCommand){
            arrayOfCommands[commandNum] = args[i];
            firstCommand = 0;
        }
        //Rest of the cases
        else{
            //if we find something that's not a pipe...
            if(strcmp(args[i], "|")){
                //Add a space to what was a previous part of the same command
                arrayOfCommands[commandNum] = strcat(arrayOfCommands[commandNum]," ");
                arrayOfCommands[commandNum] = strcat(arrayOfCommands[commandNum],args[i]);
            }
            //But if we do find a pipe...
            else if (!strcmp(args[i], "|")) {
                //We know it's time for a new command
                commandNum++;
                firstCommand = 1;
            }               
        }
        //Looking at the next value in args
        i++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < commands; i++)
        printf("Command #[%d]: %s\n", i, arrayOfCommands[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, how are you verifying that the contents of `arrayOfArgs` are gibberish?  Are you printing out the contents with `printf`?  Are you using a debugger?

Second of all, what is *each element* of `arrayOfArgs` supposed to store?  Is it supposed to be a 3-element array of strings 9 characters or less?  Is it supposed to be a 3x10 element array of pointers to `char`?  Is it supposed to be a 3x10 element array of pointers to pointers to `char`?

In the line

```
 arrayOfArgs[commandNum][count] = args[i];
```

the expression `args[i]` has type `char *`; that strongly implies that you intend for each element of `arrayOfArgs` to store a `char *`.  In that case, change the declaration of `arrayOfArgs` to

```
char *arrayOfArgs[commands][10];
```

(I read this as each command can have up to 9 arguments).

IOW, it *looks* like you're trying to store something like

```
    col     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8    9
row 
  0       "cmd"  "a1"  "a2"  NULL  NULL  NULL ...
  1       "cmd"  "a1"  NULL
...
```

by storing pointers to each string in the 2D array.

If that's the case, then you need to change the declaration of `arrayOfArgs` as I said above.  If that's *not* the case, then you need to give us an example of what `arrayOfArgs` is *supposed* to look like.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
char **arrayOfArgs[commands][10];
```

This declares an two dimension array of double char pointers, which is not what you want.

Try the following instead:

```
char *arrayOfArgs[commands][10];
```

EDIT: changed to `char*` because after examine the code I found the OP assigning a pointer to a character array to `arrayOfArgs`. Thanks to @wildplasser for notifying.

Answer (score 0):

So I see some issues...

First I believe you mean to have `char arrayOfArgs[commands][10];` as you want a 2D array of 10 character strings (i assume this is what you want)... otherwise it would be a 2D array of an array of string pointers (so like a 4D array of characters :P)

Next the code you have created will only copy into each of those command buffers the character `|` if the argument itself is `|`

If you are looking for the contents between the pipe symbols look into the function `strchr` and `strncpy`, with these functions I would loop through each arg and if and argument is the pipe symbol, `|`, find the next argument with the pipe symbol, loop through the arguments in between and then copy the characters in between into a dynamically allocated char array

Also, in your comments you say that the commands array will be dynamic... the way you have your program structured the data is statically allocated on the stack. To make this dynamic you will need to dynamically allocate onto the heap i.e. `malloc`/`calloc`